# Can't send mail with sendmail

Tags: linux, sendmail, smtp

I use SENDMAIL, I noticed that none of my mail is sent. I have all my mail in the

```
 /var/spool/mqueue
```

when I looked at the log and I have this error

```
 MDeferred: Connection refused by cluster8a.eu.messagelabs.com.
```

What does this line mean.?

i test to see if this remote host accepts incoming SMTP connections on SMTP port 25, by way of the following command:

> telnet cluster8a.eu.messagelabs.com 25

```
telnet cluster8a.eu.messagelabs.com 25
Trying 85.158.139.103...
telnet: connect to address 85.158.139.103: Connection refused
Trying 216.82.251.230...
telnet: connect to address 216.82.251.230: Connection refused
telnet: Unable to connect to remote host: Connection refused
```

Answer (score 2):

This line mean that connection to port 25 (stmp) was refused. So either this host is blocking your smtp connection or smtp on this host is stopped. If you get this messages only for this one host then probably everything is ok with your smtp deamon(try send mail to other host and check logs to confirm that this problem is only with cluster8a.eu.messagelabs.com).

Comment: hello, how can i do this

Comment: Do what send mail to another host ?? Same you send to this one.

Comment: Try telnet to port 25 on some other host, perhaps your ISP's mail server? If that doesn't work, either, you have a firewall issue or some other general networking problem. Many ISPs block outbound port 25 entirely for spam-control reasons.